# iOS 6.1 and Xcode 4.6, enumaration warning UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut

Tags: iphone, ios, enums, xcode4.6

i have installed the new iOS 6.1 and Xcode 4.6, and now i have some warning of enumeration in my code, i can't resolve this:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                          delay:0.0
                        options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{

                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
```

and this is the warning:

```
Implicit conversion from enumeration type 'enum UIViewAnimationCurve' to different enumeration type 'UIViewAnimationOptions' (aka 'enum UIViewAnimationOptions')
```

how i can solve this warning?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

You're using the wrong option value. Try `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut`.

Comment: Came across the same problem when going through this RW tutorial: http://www.raywenderlich.com/2454/how-to-use-uiview-animation-tutorial Thanks Kevin Ballard!

Comment: on adding UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut getting error " Use of undeclared identifier 'animationOptions'"

Comment: @Naresh make sure you are passing in delay: 0.0f param before the options: param. thus it is animateWithDuration: delay: options: animations: completion:

Answer (score 2):

Replace `UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut` into `UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut`

**Eg:**

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.4
                          delay:0.0
                        UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                     animations:^{

                     } completion:^(BOOL finished) {}];
```