# Xcode 5 and IOS 7 enumaration warning UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut

Tags: ios, enums, xcode5

hi im trying to create side number side menu but getting a warning i have seached many option nothing had worked for me pls help me

the code i have used :

```
-(void) animatedLayerToPoint:(CGFloat)x
 {
    [UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:0.3 delay:0  
         options:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut 
         animations:^{
                              CGRect frame = self.toplayer.frame;
                              frame.origin.x = x;
                              self.toplayer.frame = frame;
                          }
                          completion:^(BOOL finished){
                              self.layerPosition = self.toplayer.frame.origin.x;
                          }];

   }
```

this is the warning im getting

```
Implicit conversion from enumeration type 'enum UIViewAnimationCurve' to different enumeration type 'UIViewAnimationOptions' (aka 'enum UIViewAnimationOptions')
```

i seached for solution i had seen some of the ans its not working i xcode 5 [link i found solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14615417/ios-6-1-and-xcode-4-6-enumaration-warning-uiviewanimationcurveeaseout)
in above link the told to give

they telling to put this one

> UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut

instead of

> UIViewAnimationCurveEaseOut

but its not working pls i need help

Comment: You was refer to wrong link, because see your method `[UIView animateKeyframesWithDuration:0.3....` with that link `UIView animateWithDuration:0.4....`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use of this method is discouraged in iOS 4.0 and later. Instead, you should use the`animateWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:` method to specify your animations and the animation curve options.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use: [**UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions**](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/uiview/uiview.html) enum for fixing the issue.

`animateKeyframesWithDuration:` takes `UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions` option as it's 3rd argument. You are passing the `UIViewAnimationCurve` enum instead of `UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions`.

---

#### Reference:

> `animateKeyframesWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion:`
>
> Creates an animation block object that can be used to set up
>   keyframe-based animations for the current view.

```
+ (void)animateKeyframesWithDuration:(NSTimeInterval)duration delay:(NSTimeInterval)delay options:(UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions)options animations:(void (^)(void))animations completion:(void (^)(BOOL finished))completion
```

> #### Parameters
>
> **duration**
>
> The duration of the overall animation, measured in seconds. If you specify a negative value or 0, changes are made immediately and
>   without animations.
>
> **delay**
>
> Specifies the time (in seconds) to wait before starting the animation.
>
> **options**
>
> A mask of options indicating how you want to perform the animations. For a list of valid constants, see
>   “UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions”.
>
> **animations**
>
> A block object containing the changes to commit to the views. Typically, you call the
>   addKeyframeWithRelativeStartTime:relativeDuration:animations: method
>   one or more times from inside this block. You may also change view
>   values directly if you want those changes to animate over the full
>   duration. This block takes no parameters and has no return value. Do
>   not use a nil value for this parameter. completion
>
> A block object to be executed when the animation sequence ends. This block has no return value and takes a single Boolean argument
>   that indicates whether or not the animations finished before the
>   completion handler was called. If the duration of the animation is 0,
>   this block is performed at the beginning of the next run loop cycle.
>   You can use a nil value for this parameter.

Answer (score 0):

According to [apples docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiview_class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions), the options should be.

**UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions**
Key frame animation options used with the `animateKeyframesWithDuration:delay:options:animations:completion: method.` So your
Options should be as below.

```
typedef enum {
   UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews            = UIViewAnimationOptionLayoutSubviews,
   UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction      = UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction,
   UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState     = UIViewAnimationOptionBeginFromCurrentState,
   UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionRepeat                    = UIViewAnimationOptionRepeat,
   UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionAutoreverse               = UIViewAnimationOptionAutoreverse,
   UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionOverrideInheritedDuration = UIViewAnimationOptionOverrideInheritedDuration,
   UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionOverrideInheritedOptions  = UIViewAnimationOptionOverrideInheritedOptions,

   UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionCalculationModeLinear     = 0 << 9,
   UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionCalculationModeDiscrete   = 1 << 9,
   UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionCalculationModePaced      = 2 << 9,
   UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionCalculationModeCubic      = 3 << 9,
   UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptionCalculationModeCubicPaced = 4 << 9
} UIViewKeyframeAnimationOptions;
```

Otherwise It will show warning and in 64-bit application, it may lead to serious issue.

Answer (score 0):

use this option instead:

```
 UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
```

That's really all you need to change to make the warning to away.